# Conditional environment variables in Jenkinsfile

Tags: github, jenkins-pipeline

My Jenkinsfiles use the environment{} directive. I've been trying to set a condition where I invoke different variables depending on the GIT branch being builded.

I've tried something like e. g. :

```
switch(branch_name) {
   case 'dev' :
    Var1 = x;
   case 'master' :
    Var1 = y;
}
```

That would allow me skip using different Jenkinsfiles for each branch on a repo. But groovy syntax seems not to work inside this environment{} directive.

Is there a way tackling it? Or would you suggest another approach for handling different global variables for each branch?

Comment: Is this for a declarative pipeline?

Comment: @LionelOrellana yeah, It's declarative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `when` declarative in your declarative pipeline. More info [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when)

```
pipeline {
agent any
stages {
    stage('Example Build') {
        steps {
            echo 'Hello World'
        }
    }
    stage('Deploy to PROD') {
        when {
            branch 'production'
            environment name: 'DEPLOY_TO', value: 'production'
        }
        steps {
            echo 'Deploying'
        }
    }
    stage('Deploy to DEV') {
        when {
            branch 'dev'
            environment name: 'DEPLOY_TO', value: 'dev'
        }
        steps {
            echo 'Deploying'
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I also added "env." to the variables so that it created the globals.